# c# - for loop doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, browser

I'm doing a program which goes to a link + parameter (string), edits some values and hits save button.

Here's part of my code that's making problems:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s; i++)
{
  webBrowser1.Navigate("someUrl" + parameter[i]);
  timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //some code to change some values and click on a save button...
  timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Problem is, it loops only once, instead of doing it s times. I'm using a timer to wait few seconds for a page to load...

Comment: What is `s`? I think if you put something like `Console.WriteLine(i)` in your loop, you'll find that it *is* looping `s` times.

Comment: How do you know it happens only once? Have you stepped through it with the debugger?

Comment: I suspect it "works perfectly fine" but the fundamental approach is flawed. What *should* happen when this occurs: `browser.Navigate("http://foo/1"); browser.Navigate("http://foo/2");` ?? (Hint: consider waiting until the applicable "navigation complete" event.) In any case, voting to close because this is too localized (not generic enough) and doesn't include relevant debugging information.

Comment: On a side note, provided that `s` is a positive int, your current implementation will loop s+1 times since you're starting at 0.

Comment: Some thoughts: it wouldn't loop s-times, but s+1 times. And there are better ways of waiting a few seconds: `Thread.Sleep(long milliseconds)` for instance.

Comment: Seems like you might be trying to reinvent the wheel, would something like WebAii or Selenium be a more useful tool to implement for this type of work?  They have built in functionality already for waiting on page loading and click events.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEvenHandler`.

```
public void Init()
{
    myWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted +=  new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(NavigationCompleted);
}

public void Navigate()
{
    myWebBrowser.Navigate(parameter[index++]);
}

private void NavigationCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //Do what you have to do with the document loaded in the browser
     //...
     //Submit your edit form (click save button)
     //...
     Navigate(); //Next!
}
```

Comment: This doesn't necessarily allow for enough time to edit his values.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is certainly executing `s` times, but `timer1_Tick` is certainly executing only once. This is because you're enabling `timer1` over and over again in rapid-fire mode, but the timer is only disabled once, when `timer1_Tick` finally fires after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`. It allows you to run things in the background very easily and to be informed when the work is done. May be it's what you are lookg for.